# return blank row when no records sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `tblAccount`. I want to get the top 4 rows from the table. If no record is there, I want to get 4 blank rows.

```
select * 
from tblAccount

o/p
----
AccountID AccountNo
1          #101
2          #102
NULL       NULL
NULL       NULL
```

The above should be the result if two records are there.

Comment: Q: Why exactly do you need something that perverse?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  You could do the same thing with a temp table, just give it the right number of fields and rows.

```
with meganull(a,b) as (
    select CAST(null as int),
           CAST(null as varchar(max))
    union all
    select *
    from meganull
)
select top 4 *
from (
    select *
    from tblAccount
    union all
    select *
    from meganull) as sq
```

Comment: Getting a conversion error , as the field i am selecting in varchar.
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '#101' to data type int.

Comment: Just cast each field to the appropriate data type.  I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/746c9/8)

```
select TOP 4 AccountID,AccountNo
from
(
select 0 as srt,AccountID,AccountNo from tblAccount
union all
select 1 as srt,NULL as AccountID, NULL as AccountNo
union all
select 2 as srt,NULL as AccountID, NULL as AccountNo
union all
select 3 as srt,NULL as AccountID, NULL as AccountNo
union all
select 4 as srt,NULL as AccountID, NULL as AccountNo
) as t
order by srt,AccountID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Select * FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS value(tmpID) left join 
(
select Row_Number() over (order by AccountID) as RowCtr, * 
from tblAccount
) accountTable on tmpID = accountTable.RowCtr
```

I used a similar technique when I wanted a way to force a certain number of rows to display in a SSRS report, where the blank rows represented empty spots in a physical rack.